# Large MySQL Table Update Slow

Tags: mysql, performance, scalability, sql-update

Hi this is my table structure

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `sms_report` (
 `R_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `R_uid` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `R_smppid` varchar(100) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `R_from` varchar(10) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `R_status` longtext collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `R_message` text collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `R_numbers` longtext collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `R_timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
 `R_timedate` varchar(40) collate utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `R_show` int(11) NOT NULL default '1',
 `oldformat` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default '0',
 PRIMARY KEY  (`R_id`)
```

) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=1947722 ;

I have approx 2 million rows so when I do an update on R_status here, it seem to take too long(R_status is either 1,2,16 or 24).
Please suggest on how to optimise.

Comment: Are you updating based only on `R_id` in the `WHERE` clause? or other columns? can you post a sample `UPDATE` query?

Comment: sample update query would be
update sms_report set R_status=1 where R_smppid=738sbdasdbajsdbdfbfbks782|9898773122

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @BarsMonster suggestd, convert `R_status` into an integer (`TINYINT` if values are only `1,2,16,24`), and create an `INDEX` on `R_smppid`. Also, if `R_smppid` is fixed width, change field type to `char(40)` or whatever the length of the content is, or if it can be converted into an integer, that's even better.

Comment: When you create an index, databases engine caches a version of the field ordered for easy and quick lookup upon request, so when you do `UPDATE.. WHERE indexed_field=value` next time, the database finds that row much faster, and update it, take a look here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html

Answer (score 3):

If R_status is always integer, make it integer.
Also, I would try to convert this table into fixed-row-width format (no varchars/texts)

Also, make index on R_smppid, without that it would do full table scan on each update.